# Admob interstitial ads on 2.2

Tags: android, admob

I want to implement interstitial (full screen ads) from Admob in my game, but I want to support Android 2.2.

Now admob SDK go with Google play services and require 2.3+ android. There is services for froyo (2.2), but in this library there is now admob support (as I know)

Is there any way to implement interstitial ads from admob in 2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and quite honestly you should consider the business value of attempting to support Android 2.2 since it has such a minute (and falling0 market share.

Comment: This is true for new applications/games, but I have existing game with 7% of users on 2.2 and I don't want to lose them

Comment: Don't lose them as users, just write them off as paying customers. Ie don't worry if you are not delivering ads to them. This is a business decision. What is the cost of implementing a complicated work around to get revenue from 7% of your user base and what is that revenue worth. How long will that revenue continue (their phones will die or be traded in at some point).